# How can i access facebook page likes data using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api

I have already implemented a code for accessing logged facebook user via our website for that i have created AppID and appSecret Key and it will return all data(eg.email,likes,birthday,friends).
but the problem is if logged user is only having a page then my Graph API string will not fetch result properly it only contains ID nothing else.

My code to get user details.

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new FacebookExtendedClient(
           "655618811231635",
           "a05a82145a29f38a117f66ba56345081",
           "email,likes",
           new Func<string, object, string>(fieldsTransformer),
           "email"));
```

and this is for getting me result.

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        facebookClient.AppId = "655618811231635";
        facebookClient.AppSecret = "a05a82145a29f38a117f66ba56345081";
        var getResult = facebookClient.Get<IDictionary<string, object>>("me", new { fields = this.fields });
```

if logged user is simple user(which having friends,groups etc) then it will work like charm but if it is user which having a Page in it then it will not display any result.

Comment: Do you mean a user logged in as a page? You need the pages permission set and also page access tokens to get data from a page user.

Comment: right now i only got Access token, and i dont have user ID to get page access token?

Comment: if i create query me/accounts it only give me result blank data array,but i already give manage_pages,read_insights,read_stream permission.

Comment: If you have a user access token with manage_pages permission, you should be seeing the pages managed by the you with me/accounts. Try it out first in the graph explorer

Comment: yes i tried it on graph explorer but it will display this,{
  "data": [
  ]
}

Comment: i found actual problem when user logged in from my website it will only show a dialog box for public profile info not for manage_pages so how can get manage_pages permission using above code?

Comment: ok solution is your application must have manage_pages permission for that you need to submit your review to facebook to get that permission after that when ever user logged in dialog box appear with all permissions.